# invoking mathtype from texsudio

Tags: macros, texstudio, javascript

Any idea how can I automatically invoke Mathtype from texstudio using macro (javascript) and put the formula back onto texstudio automatically. It can be done manually, but I want to know is it possible to do this in an automated manner like when invoking mathtype from word.

Comment: If it can be done with help of batch files, you can build your own command. Then add a button to your toolbar or use a keyboard shortcut.
I don't know Mathtype ... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Mathtype, but if it can export to the clipboard, you can use the following macro (I just use notepad.exe as an example external application):

```js
%SCRIPT
proc = system("c:/windows/notepad.exe")
proc.waitForFinished()
// as a user you can now work in the external application
// when you're done, copy the required content to the clipboard
// and close the external application
editor.paste()
```

Comment: Presumably this is a Windows-only technique, although you don't say so?

Comment: This script works independent of the OS. `system()` starts a new process. Of course, you wouldn't have `notepad.exe` on other OSs but that's just an example anyway. Just replace it by the desired program.

Comment: The notepad version worked but my alteration for Mathtype doesn't work.  The code is like: proc = system("MathType.exe", workingDirectory="c:/Program Files (x86)/MathType/") I think the problem is with the system(). Is there any other command which I can use instead of it. 
proc.waitForFinished()
editor.paste()

Comment: Try specifying the complete path to `MathType.exe`.

Comment: Have been tried not working. seems that the directory is not accessible.

Comment: If the path contains spaces, you have to enquote it: `system('"c:‌​/Program Files (x86)/MathType/MathType.exe"')`. Otherwise everyting after the first space is considered to be parameters.